# Parse String to pull US State... but String may or may not contain city

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am looking to parse a string and take the state name from a field of data. Here is my issue: There is a comma and a city often times in the field, so I need to pull the state name that which is AFTER the comma. The kicker is sometimes there isn't a city and sometimes there is :[

Here is what I am thinking: Regardless of containing a city or not, it does contain the state names. I could put the 50 states into a table and use a LIKE Statement for the field, so regardless of a comma or not, it will pickup the state names. The issue becomes if a city might be the name of a state, or if part of a city name contains the state name... hrmmm. Does anyone have any tips?

In addition, I need a way to pull the city for another field! That one is tough because I'm not going to be able to have a database table of all the cities to compare to.

```
Sample data set: 
ANCHORAGE, ALASKA
BLOOMINGTON, MINNESOTA
FLORIDA
HENDERSON, NEVADA
NEW JERSEY
OKLAHOMA CITY, OKLAHOMA
```

Comment: Split on comma and take the last element in the resulting arry.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. It can't be both VBA and SQL (because they're totally different animals), so pick one and remove the other tag. Second, you haven't explained what "parse a string and take the state name" means. What do you want to do with that "state name" you've "taken"? What does "pull the city for another field!" mean? You've said there might not be a city, so what would you "pull" in that case?

Comment: Is it always `CITY,STATE`?

Comment: It is always CITY, STATE - But that is only if the City is present. As you can see in the sample data, sometimes it just doesn't include the city. Also when I say parse the string, I mean a SQL Code to Move that field into separate City and State Columns.

Comment: @KenWhite In MS Access, SQL and VBA are related. You can have a User Defined Function in VBA that you refer to with Access SQL.

Comment: Do you have a list of States in a separate table, if so, the solution is very easy indeed.

Comment: @Fionnuala: Yes, I'm aware of that fact. However, the answer to the question would depend on whether the poster was attempting to do the parsing in SQL or via a VBA function, and as it is stated there's no indication of which is being attempted. (Actually, there's no information about **anything** being attempted, which was part of the point of the comment. The poster should [edit] the question to a) clarify what they are trying to do, and b) include some effort to actually solve the problem first before posting here.)

Comment: @KenWhite My point was that it could be both. I agree it is not a well structured question.

Answer (score 1):

**1.**
If the string follows a structure, you can try to recognize it (such as in NLP).
Ex.
Structure 1: [city], [prov], [country], [continent], [planet]
Structure 2: [prov], [country]

Then all you have to do is recognize the structure. You can use number of elements, and the position of a recognized item (ex. State/Prov) to get the structure.

**2.**
If there is no structure, or too many variations to consider, I'd use recognition of items and their relation.
Ex. You can recognize a state, and you know that if the string has a city it will be right before the state. So check to see if there is a string before the state and that the string looks like a city name, then save it.

This is more likely to return false results (if there is no structure and you can't recognize a city's name, there's only so much that can be done to identify one)

**3.**
Looking at your last comment about format always being "[state]" or "[city], [state]". I may have overestimated your problem. If the format is really only those 2, then do what Tim Williams suggested.

Split the string, using the delimiter ", "
Make the state the last element in the split array, and if the size of the split array is 2 (ex. Ubound - Lbound + 1 = 2) then make the city the first element in the split array

VBA Code for method 3:

```
Sub test()
    s1 = "Alaska"
    s2 = "Anchorage, Alaska"
    s3 = "Texas"
    MsgBox parse(s1) & vbNewLine & parse(s2) & vbNewLine & parse(s3)
End Sub

Function parse(str As Variant) As String
    Dim state As String, city As String
    Dim splitArr() As String
    Dim output As String

    splitArr = Split(str, ", ")
    length = UBound(splitArr) - LBound(splitArr) + 1

    state = splitArr(UBound(splitArr))
    output = "State: " & state
    If length > 1 Then
        city = splitArr(LBound(splitArr))
        output = "City: " & city & ", " & output
    End If
    parse = output
End Function
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused on how best to use split. I say that because if a city is present than it's Variant 0. If it's only the state than the State becomes Variant 0. Do you have an example to use that will consistently work in a SQL query?

Comment: Updated answer, is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a table of States, you can say:

```
SELECT Address.Address, State.State
FROM State, Address
WHERE Address.Address Like "*" & [State] & "*"
```

This is only awkward if you have Florida, New Jersey.